# display a message to user if field is blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Afternoon Folks,

I am new to c# and im trying to create an if statement to check the value of two fields and if both of these fields are blank, to then display a message to the user.

My two fields are DateofBirth with a datatype of DateTime and Age with a datatype of int.  Im using studio 2013 and have a c# mvc project.

In my create.cshtml page i am using razor syntax for these two form fields.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.client.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "dd-mm-yyyy" } })
```

and

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.client.AgeNotKnown, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Age in Years" } })
```

the user needs to fill in either one or the other field when submitting the form.

In my controller and my HttpPost for the ActionResult Create.  I have tried a couple of ways to get this working via an if statement but i get seem to get this to work.

I have tried using the string.IsNullOrEmpty method, but as these are DateTime and int datatypes this will not work.  See sample below.

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientViewRecord.client.AgeNotKnown));              
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please an Age if DOB not known");
            }

 db.ClientRecords.Add(clientViewRecord.client);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("MainMenu", "Home");
```

I get three errors here:

1. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?' to 'string'
2. The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context 3)   The
   best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has
   some invalid arguments
3. The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has
   some invalid arguments

Another way i have tried to get this working is the following...

```
     if (clientViewRecord.client.AgeNotKnown == 0 || clientViewRecord.client.DateOfBirth == 0);              
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter an Age or if DOB");
            }

            db.ClientRecords.Add(clientViewRecord.client);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("MainMenu", "Home");
```

I get the same issue for the message box and the following for the DateofBirth filed.

1. Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int'

Im new to c# but think that im kinda on the right lines, i think just need a little help or any suggestions.

Regards
Betty

Comment: `MessageBox` is window forms (it no use in a web app). Add a `ModelState` error and return the view so the message is displayed in your `@Html.ValidationSummary()` - ModelState.AddModelError("", "your error message");  return View(model);`

Comment: And make your properties nullable - `int? AgeNotKnown` and `DateTime? DateOfBirth` so that you test them with `if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)`

Comment: But the correct way to handle this uis to create a custom validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` so you get both client and server side validation - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  many thanks, both of my fields are nullable in my model.   public Nullable<int> AgeNotKnown { get; set; }, public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }.  I will take a look at the guide you have referenced in your message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` means `nullable` whose default value will be `null` if i use `int?` its default value will be `null` if i use `int` its default value will be `0`

about validation you can use `ModelState` for validation in `MVC` and add a custom validation

```
    @Html.ValidationMessage("validation")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "dd-mm-yyyy" } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgeNotKnown, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Age in Years" } })
```

i used  `@Html.ValidationMessage("validation")` which will show the validation message if i return any and in your `action`

```
 if (cls.DateOfBirth == null && cls.AgeNotKnown == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("validation","Please select one");
                return View();
            }
```

in action it will check condition if both are `null` then it will return to the same view including the validation message of `key` `validation` which is defined in the view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all MessageBox class is belong to windows forms. If you want to wanr the user you should use validations. I prefer [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

To add control like this, just put a breakpoint to your code and look want data coming from your form. This way you can decide how do you want to control your data.

System.DateTime? and int?, this question marks tell you that these variables can be null. So you should consider that while comparing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create ViewModel for this kind of validation

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In View

```
@model  Models.ClientViewModel @*reference to your model usally create in Models folder*@

@Html.ValidationSummary() @* add this for validation summary displays here.*@

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "dd-mm-yyyy" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Age in Years" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Age)

@* Add jqueryval bundles which is created in app_start/BundleConfig  *@
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

In Controller

```
//Change the name of PostMethod 
public ActionResult PostMethod(Models.ClientViewModel model )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }


    return View();
}
```